# Hibernate Unable to find logical name

Tags: java, hibernate

I have encountered this exception

```
Caused by:
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: picture_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(TXN_INVENTORY_PICTURE) and its related supertables and secondary tables
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:564)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:258)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1596)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1519)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1420)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
```

Here's a gist of the classes that are involve

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_PRODUCT")
public class Product extends JpaModel{

    @Column(name= "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "MANUFACTURER")
    private String manufacturer;

    /**
     * Work around for missing
     */
    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="picture",referencedColumnName = "picture_id")
    private InventoryItemPicture picture;
}
```

And here's The inventoryItemPicutre

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TXN_INVENTORY_PICTURE")
public class InventoryItemPicture extends JpaModel{

    @Column
    private byte[] image;

    @Column
    private String fileName;

    public InventoryItemPicture(){

    }
....
}
```

And here's the JPAModel

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class JpaModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name ="ID", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private DateTime createdDate;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
}
```

NOTE: Omitted the setters and getters,and what I am trying to achieve here is The picture can be null in the Product class

Comment: Is there a column `picture_id` in table `TXN_INVENTORY_PICTURE`?

Comment: @PredragMaric none, but it has an id field.

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in your mapping, `referencedColumnName` targets the column `picture_id` in `TXN_INVENTORY_PICTURE` table, which doesn't exist.

If `picture_id` is the name of the column in `REF_PRODUCT` table which is a foreign key to `TXN_INVENTORY_PICTURE` table, then change the mapping to this

```
@OneToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name="picture_id")
private InventoryItemPicture picture;
```

Comment: Already tried that but it showed an error a non-null constraint. What I want is the picture object can also be set to null

Comment: I've edited my answer, can't be sure though of the exact names without database structure, but you'll get the idea. If database is created from entity model with these annotations, then `picture_id` will be created as nullable. If database is already created, and `picture_id` is not nullable, change it directly in database to nullable. JPA uses these annotations only to generate database schema from entity model.

Comment: Already tried it. I used the Entity Models to Generate the tables for me, however the foreign key picture_id is always set to Non-null. I must specifically changed in the DB, is there workaround for this

Comment: That's strange. With these annotations `picture_id` should be created as nullable. Are you sure that's not the case when generating a new database?

Comment: Tried it again with a new DB. however it still persists. I updated my question, I added the JpaModel maybe that would help

Comment: Did you try it with annotations from my answer? With `picture_id` column in `REF_PRODUCT` table?